# Can I use Talend to display indicators in dashboard?

Tags: reporting, talend, dashboard

Can I use Talend to display indicators in dashboard ? If not, which tool can I have to use?

Comment: This completely depends on your requirements, your situation and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Because, usually, Talend is used to manipulate data, and a presentation tool, like Jaspersoft, QlikView, Power BI... is used to display the data. BUT if you want to display performance data of your ETL jobs, you might be able to use Talend as well. So... it depends.